# ForEach перебор массива

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь отфильтровать повторяющиеся элементы и занести результат в другой массив.

```
let arr = ["php", "php", "css", "css", "script", "script", "html", "html", "java"]; // (ИЗНАЧАЛЬНЫЙ МАССИВ)
```

Мой код:

```
let arr = ["php", "php", "css", "css", "script", "script", "html", "html", "java"];
let result = [];
arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    for(let j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
        if (item[i] !== arr[j]) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    }
 
})

document.writeln(result);  // [php,css,script,html,java] ожидаемый результат
```

Я беру цикл из изначального массива (forEach), потом запускаю внутри него еще один цикл, который плюсует на 1 значение индекса (j), а затем сами элементы я сравниваю на схожесть по индексу, если не схож то пушу в другой массив. Но в ходе выполнения получается другой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала обратите внимание, что `item[i]` — наверняка ошибка. Поскольку `item` тут всегда строка и вы просто берёте из неё символ по индексу `i` и сравниваете его с целым элементом массива.

Comment: Далее. Если исправить на `if (item !== arr[j]) result.push(item);` — это будет по сути означать вот что: каждый раз, когда текущий элемент не равен одному из элементов массива, вставить его в массив. Поэтому вы получаете столько повторений. Если у вас два одинаковых элемента и ещё семь отличающихся, каждый из двух одинаковых элементов будет вставлен в массив семь раз.

Comment: вот так вроде : https://jsfiddle.net/05jzyknt/

Comment: @MaximLensky, так вроде, только 1-й пробег зачем

Comment: я не умею по другому

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать `Set`, в котором все элементы по одному, а потом обратно массив.

```js
const arr = ["php", "php", "css", "css", "script", "script", "html", "html", "java","php"]
console.log([...new Set(arr)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```js
 let arr = ["php", "php", "css", "css", "script", "script", "html", "html", "java","php"];
let result = [];
document.writeln(arr+"<br>")
for (let str of arr)
{
    if (!result.includes(str)) {
        result.push(str);
    }
}
document.writeln(result+"<br>")
```

Comment: сложность тут квадратичная, если что